# deserialized object from json into dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I have deserialized an object from JSON:

```
dynamic bookdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bookdata_);
dynamic boy = orderbookdata.asks;
```

Now the dynamic `boy` holds the following data:

```
{[ [25,32], [33,44], [22,11], [57.98,2.22] ]}
```

I would like to put this data into a more organised format instead of holding it in `boy`. E.g. a dictionary etc...

The json structure is like this:

```
{
    "name": "aal",
    "symbol": "ltd",
    "timestamp": 1464703002,
    "asks": [
        [25, 32],
        [33, 44],
        [22, 11],
        [57.98, 2.22]
    ]
}
```

I would like to extract `[25, 32], [33, 44], [22, 11], [57.98, 2.22]` into each single values and pop on to a two columns list view.

Comment: Should this read `dynamic boy = bookdata.asks;`? Also, please post the structure of your JSON.

Comment: yes indeed, and the structure is like this: {"name":"aal","symbol":"ltd","timestamp":1464703002,"asks":[ [ 25, 32 ], [ 33, 44 ], [ 22, 11 ], [ 57.98, 2.22 ]]}

Comment: and i would like to extract [ 25, 32 ], [ 33, 44 ], [ 22, 11 ], [ 57.98, 2.22 ] into each single values and pop on to a two columns list view, sorry about the confusion caused

Comment: Please add to question

Answer (score 1):

If `dynamic` `boy` holds the following data `{[ [ 25, 32 ], [ 33, 44 ], [ 22, 11 ], [ 57.98, 2.22 ]]}`, then see the code below:

```
dynamic bookdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bookdata_);
dynamic boy = orderbookdata.asks;
double[][] e = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)boy)
                 .Select(b => ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)b)
                                .Cast<double>()
                                .ToArray())
                 .ToArray();
```

If `Dictionary<first_value, second_value>` is required:

```
dynamic bookdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bookdata_);
dynamic boy = orderbookdata.asks;
Dictionary<double, double> d = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)boy)
                                 .Select(b => ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)b)
                                                .Cast<double>())
                                 .ToDictionary(i => i.First(), i => i.Last());
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[]' to 'double[][]'

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<double>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, double>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Missed openning brackets. Fixed.